# calculate the index of column in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, sum

I want to get the summation of 2d array per column, and i don't know why it's adding everything.

```
let vals = [
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1]
];
 total = 0;
   for (let i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
     for (let j = 0; j < vals.length; j++) {
       total += vals[j][i];
     }
     console.log(total);
   }
```

output:

```
3
6
9
```

what i need:

```
3
3
3
```

```js
let vals = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]];
total = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < vals.length; j++) {
    total += vals[j][i];
  }
  console.log(total);
}
```

Comment: Initialize `total` inside the loop, else it'll never reset

Comment: @ CertainPerformance, but why is the output of total when initialize inside the for loop only give same value?
like the `vals = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]];`. The output of this is just 3 not 
`3, 3, 3` ?

Comment: because `total` is a number not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let vals = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]];
total = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < vals.length; j++) {
    total += vals[j][i];
  }
  console.log(total);
  total = 0;
}
```

you need to reset ***total*** after inner loop is finished.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize `total` for each row.

```js
let vals = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]];

for (let i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
   let total = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < vals.length; j++) {
    total += vals[j][i];
  }
  console.log(total);
}
```